# varchar To Date Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I I'm tryng to convert a varchar (04/07/2025)into a date 2025-07-04 but I've an error when find 31/09/2024 and return out of range value

```
select
    id, 
    documento,
    case 
        WHEN documento = null
        THEN  null
        WHEN documento = ''  
        THEN  null
        WHEN documento not like '%%/%%/%%%%' 
        THEN  null  
        --WHEN documento not like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9]%'
        --then null
        ELSE TO_Date(documento,'DD/MM/YYYY')        
    end as dt_scadenza_documento_id
from tab;
```

can you help me please?

Comment: Well, September only has 30 days, so 31/09/2024 is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can I handle this exception?